# ¿Es posible tener acciones programadas a través de un Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, pwa, service-workers

Me encontré con una duda: ¿Es posible ejecutar una función a cierta hora todos los días a través de un serviceWorker?

Este es un problema completamente nuevo para mi, me disculpo por no dejar código, seria de mucha ayuda si pudieran ayudarme con algún ejemplo de esto, gracias.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], al momento tu pregunta solo tiene dos posibles respuestas si o no

Comment: Si, para que mires con mas detalle https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers?hl=es